# How to manage concurrency on a filesystem resource from two different programs (on different address spaces)?

Tags: xml, file, concurrency, mutex, multilingual

Well my problem is a bit complex, but not so much, I'll describe now in these few lines.
Let us say I have two programs in two different languages. One program writes a file and that same file is read by the other program. The file is the coupling unit for both the applications, it is some sort of loose coupling (not something I designed, just an old application I have to manage with).

Well as you undoubtably understand this is a shared resource issue, but how to manage it?
Well I came to a solution.

When a program has to read/write, asks to the other application (via TCP) and get an ok-go, or a retry-later. Well I was wondering whether it was possible to have a different approach.
I also thought about SENDING the file content periodically to the program who reads the file (because one writes and the other one reads only).

I also thought about not caring of concurrency. Ok it is possible that the program who reads the file will read a non consistent file, if you consider that the file is an xml file, the problem is even greater, suppose that the writing program did not finish to write a closing tag and the reading program tries to read the content. It will get an exception: not well formed file exception or similar :) But is it so bad?? If this happens, I'll close the file, set a timer and try again later. Isn't it a valid approach (sure it is fast), it might also end up being the best approach. What do you think about it?

Is there a valid algorithm used for such cases?

Thank you.

Comment: Strategies would vary from OS to OS.  You can modify both programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use case for file locking.  How to use file locks is OS-dependent, so check [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) to point you in the right direction.

You would  use locks like this:  when your writer wants to modify the file, it gets and exclusive lock on the file, modifies it, and unlocks it.  When a reader wants to read the file, it gets a shared lock, reads it, then unlocks it.  If your program ever fails to acquire the lock, it should either (1) block until it can get the lock, or (2) try back later, depending on what's acceptable for your program and what your OS provides.

This keeps your data consistent, regardless of the mechanism you use to notify programs to re-read the file.

Comment: I thought of this too and this is a good solution. Well, I think I'd rather use an agreemnet algorithm, it sounds better. However thank you for your answer, it was good, I could get many information using the link you provided.